# How to restore a classlist with vanilla js

Tags: javascript, css, random

I'm manipulating a classlist on a div with JS, adding a class with a random number e.g. `target--random-number-2`.

I essentially want to 'restore' or 'reset' the classlist the next time the function is called, to re-add another class with a random number, so that I don't end up with multiple classes such as `target--random-number-1 target--random-number-2 target--random-number-3`. What's the best way to do this?

Here's my clumsy attempt (which doesn't work):

```
function random_class_number(){
    // if we've changed the target...
    if (document.querySelector('#target').classList.contains('target-has-random-number')) {
        // restore the previous classlist
        document.querySelector('#target').classList = stored_classlist;
    } else {
        // if we haven't yet changed the target, store the classlist
        var stored_classlist = document.querySelector('#target').classList;
    }

    const random_number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
    document.querySelector('#target').classList.add('target--random-number-' + random_number);
    document.querySelector('#target').classList.add('target-has-random-number');
}
```

P.s. I'm trying to move away from jQuery, so no jQuery answers please.

Comment: Store the original value somewhere else (custom data attribute, jQuery’s .data), and read it back from there.

Comment: I've actually never used the data attribute. That was a revelation! Although it's not the solution I was initially looking for, I think it's solved my problem with the minimal amount of code. For anyone having similar issues, I'll post my solution in an answer below.

Comment: _“Although it's not the solution I was initially looking for”_ - yeah, I kinda figured ... but this is just way easier ;-) Of course you could use `classList.remove` to first of all remove all possible `target--random-number-x` classes the element could have, before you then add a new random one, or something like that.

Comment: If you needed this for more “levels”, like say you were adding _two_ of those random classes and wanted to remove only one of them again, then this might need a different approach with more complex logic. But since you only want to add one class, and then go back to the original state, storing the original is just easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to cBroe's suggestion, this is what I went with something like this in the end, which didn't end up affecting my existing CSS.

```
function random_class_number(){
    const random_number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
    document.querySelector('#target').dataset.javascript = 'target--random-number-' + random_number;
}

CSS

[data-javascript="target--random-number-1"] {
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- You can use `data-attributes` to store your current classes.
- You can create `data-attributes` on the fly.

```js
function random_class_number() {
  var target = document.querySelector('#target');
  
  if (target.classList.contains('target-has-random-number')) {
    target.classList.add(...target.dataset.classes.split(/\s+/g));
    console.log('Contains');
  } else {
    console.log('Doesnt contain');
    // target.classList.value returns a string of the current classList collection.
    target.dataset.classes = target.classList.value.split(/\s+/g).join(' '); // This is to keep the initial classes separated by one space.
  }

  const random_number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
  target.classList.add('target--random-number-' + random_number, 'target-has-random-number'); // You can pass multiple classes in one call of function 'add'.
}

random_class_number();
console.log(document.querySelector('#target'));

random_class_number();
console.log(document.querySelector('#target'));
```

```css
.initial-class:before {
  content: 'initial-class - '
}

.initial-class:after {
  content: ' - initial-class2'
}
```

```html
<div class='initial-class       initial-class2' id='target'>DIV</div>
```

## Resources

- [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)
- [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)